# Why am I getting the following error after adding flutter_geofire?

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to do an assignment that I am to submit next week and I just started getting this error.

[Fatal Error] gradle-4.1.3.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_geofire'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_geofire:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3.
> Required by:
> project :flutter_geofire
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_geofire' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_geofire' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 12m 39s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have run flutter clean, flutter upgrade, I have tried changing my classpath still not working.
Please I really need help?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: My gradle version is 8.5, I am using the current version.